# Why does a video file created with ffmpeg not load properly in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ffmpeg, video-processing

Previously, I used HandBrake to encode a video and was able to read it into MATLAB without any issues. Now I'm trying to use ffmpeg to encode the video; however, MATLAB is only reading in black frames. Both HandBrake and ffmpeg are using h.264 (mp4) and both videos play fine in VLC.

Here is the command I'm using for the ffmpeg encoding.

```
ffmpeg -i Barrier.avi -c:v libx264 -b:v 500k outputt5.mp4
```

Comment: It may be useful to run HandBrake in verbose mode so that you can see exactly what parameters are being used. Then you could look into [what parameters](http://superuser.com/questions/550710/how-do-i-translate-handbrakecli-options-to-ffmpeg-options) exactly that you need to pass to ffmpeg to replicate it.

Comment: You need to provide the complete console output from your `ffmpeg` command. Without it we can only provide guesses, not answers.

Comment: FFmpeg commamd
picture 1 http://s11.postimg.org/3vch1bj83/ffmpeg1.png
picture 2 http://s29.postimg.org/6053xgglz/ffmpeg2.png